# ancestry named scopes ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I need some help understanding how to make named scopes work in ancestry. The documentation says,

> Where possible, the navigation methods return scopes instead of records, this means additional ordering, conditions, limits, etc. can be applied and that the result can be either retrieved, counted or checked for existence. For example:
>   ​

```
 node.children.exists?(:name => 'Mary')
 node.subtree.all(:order => :name, :limit => 10).each do; ...; end
 node.descendants.count
```

So, in the console, I did the following:

```
@standard = Standard.find(2693)  
Standard Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `standards`.* FROM `standards` WHERE `standards`.`id` = 2693 LIMIT 1
=> #<Standard id: 2693, ancestry: "3/2692", section_number: "1910.132",  title: "§ 1910.132  General requirements.", content: "§ 1910.132  General requirements.", created_at: "2015-11-30 20:48:04", updated_at: "2015-12-01 19:30:29", ancestry_depth: 2, role: "SECTION", section_number_suffix: 132, record_order: 2693>
```

```
@standard.descendants.count
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `standards` WHERE (`standards`.`ancestry` LIKE '3/2692/2693/%' OR `standards`.`ancestry` = '3/2692/2693')
=> 35
```

Good so far, until...

```
@standard.subtree.all(:order => :record_order)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from /home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:24:in `all'
```

Am I doing something silly?

Comment: Looks like the `all` method doesn't take arguments. I'm not familiar with ancestry, but from a glimpse at the docs wouldn't `@standard.subtree.arrange(:order => :record_order)` achieve your goal?

Comment: arrange is what I'm currently using, but I have to use a recursive method to display the results, and I'm getting performance as bad as this:

`Rendered standards/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5467.3ms)`
`Completed 200 OK in 5651ms (Views: 5549.0ms | ActiveRecord: 66.2ms)`

I was hoping to be able to get the results in a simple array and forgo the recursion.

Comment: How large is the data set? If it's small-ish, you can load it all in memory with `@standard.subtree.all` and sort it afterwards.

Comment: It's about 24,000 records; somewhere around 40M in mysql

Comment: `@standard.subtree.all` does indeed put it in a flat array.  Right now, it even has the correct ordering (the order it was scraped in). My worry is what will happen if I insert a record and the primary id no longer matches the order.  I'll have to brush up on array sorting-- because I have to follow the hierarchy first and then sort the leaves according to `record_order`.  Right now I'm not sure how to do it :/

Comment: In that case I'd suggest making a new question with the problem that you described in the last comment. The answer to the ArgumentError is that the `all` method takes no arguments, hence `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` - 0 expected, 1 given.